# I have a code that opens excel application with win32com and similar code with xlwings

Tags: win32com, xlwings

The code looks like this:

```
wbtest = xw.Book('test1.xlsx')
    
ws1 = wbtest.sheets['Sheet1']
ws1.range("A1").value ="100"
wbtest.save()
wbtest.save(r'C:\Users\afoto001.000\Desktop\All projects\DC projects\codes\test1.xlsx')
wb.kill()
```

The code basically starts an excel document and writes 100 to Sheet1. After that, I'd like Excel to close on its own, without the need for user intervention. Any suggestions or ideas would be much appreciated.

Comment: Look at the last line. `wb` is nowhere defined, it should be `wbtest.kill()`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you are closing Excel without user intervention? If this whole thing was called from a script or a cron like scheduler then the whole thing could be run without user intervention.

```
import xlwings as xw

app = xw.App()
wbtest = app.books.open(r'path\to\test1.xlsx')
ws1 = wbtest.sheets['Sheet1']
ws1.range("A1").value ="100"
wbtest.save()
wbtest.save(r'C:\Users\afoto001.000\Desktop\All projects\DC projects\codes\test1.xlsx') # Are you saving to two places?
app.quit()
app.kill() # The instance will still be there without this.

# wb.kill() You did not have an instance of wb in your code.
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this at the end of my code and now my Excel processes close automatically:

```
quit()
sys.exit()
def quit(self):
        self.xlBook.Close(SaveChanges=0)
        self.xlApp.Quit()
        del self.xlApp
```